# Weird behaviour with angularjs ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following code, which is a template of directive:

```
<div ng-click="showDetails=true" ng-init="showDetails=false">
    <div ng-show="showDetails">
        <div ng-click="showDetails=false">X</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the outer div, the inner div shows, but when I click on the 'X', it doesn't go away. When I rewrite the code, and use 'ng-mouseover' instead of 'ng-click', it works fine (i.e. first click makes the div appear, hovering over the 'X', makes it disappear):

```
<div ng-click="showDetails=true" ng-init="showDetails=false">
    <div ng-show="showDetails">
        <div ng-mouseover="showDetails=false">X</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone has a clue what might be the problem of 'ng-click' not working?
Thank you

Comment: please provide your controller!

Comment: I don't have a controller for this directive. Instead, it's instantiated many times inside an outer directive which has a controller that has no functionality regarding this specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your click event is propagating up, so after setting showDetails to false, it then sets it to true again in the outermost div! Try this:

```
<div ng-click="showDetails=true" ng-init="showDetails=false">
    <div ng-show="showDetails">
        <div ng-click="showDetails=false;$event.stopPropagation()">X</div>
    </div>
</div>
```